# How to get the #fragment identifier part of an URL

Tags: phoenix-framework

In Phoenixframework I want to know full URL path that is being requested so I tried to use `<%= @conn.request_path %>`.
The problem is that I'm requesting :`/spa.html#pageone` and I'm getting only `/spa.html`.
What is the correct way of also getting the `#fragment` identifier part of it?

Comment: The part after the `#` is called the `fragment identifier` if that helps you search your docs.

Comment: Isn't the # a comment in the phoenix-framework? just a guess but is con.request_post a thing?

Comment: @JohnHascall Thank you for that!

Comment: @kpie. Yes, it is the Elixir comment symbol, but in the request is the fragment identifier (as John Hascall pointed out). `conn.request_post` doesn't exist (I'm getting an error).

Comment: Where can I find a list of methods applicable to conn?

Comment: @kpie Here:https://hexdocs.pm/plug/extra-readme.html#The-Plug-Conn

Comment: Is the host variable public? Honestly I'm probably not the guy to answer your question...

Comment: @kpie I don't know...Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fragment is not available on the server side.

From [RFC2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4.1)

> When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after the retrieval action has been successfully completed. As such, it is not part of a URI, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.

You can access it in JavaScript with [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash).

Answer (score 1):

If using in a Live View, add a hook in app.js

```js
hooks.Fragment = {
  mounted() {
    const fragment = window.location.hash
    this.pushEvent("token", { fragment: fragment })
  },
};
```

then create a hidden div with the hook in your page

```html
<div id="flash" class="hidden" phx-hook="Fragment" style="display:none;">MAGIC DIV</div>
```

and handle the event in your Live View

```
def handle_event("token", %{"fragment" => fragment}, socket) do
    fragments =
      fragment
      |> String.trim_leading("#")
      |> URI.decode_query()
      |> Map.new(fn {k, v} -> {String.to_atom(k), v} end)
end
```