# Create a query string for a URL in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix application, I want to add a query string to a URL:

```
some_cool_path(@conn, :index, "view-mode": "table")
```

I expected that it would generate a URL like `/some_cool?view-mode=table`, but instead it throws an exception:

```
protocol Phoenix.Param not implemented for ["view-mode": "table"]
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: Can you post the router code where you've defined this route?

Comment: @Dogbert, just an ordinary route `get "some_cooll", Controller1, :action1`

Comment: Your code is correct if you've got the controller and action names right. That error message indicates that the route actually has a mandatory parameter in the URL. `post_path(MyApp.Endpoint, :index, "view-mode": "table") #=> "/posts?view-mode=table"`. Can you paste the exact line in the router that generates `some_cool_path` helper?

Comment: @Dogbert, no problem, I've fixed it.

Comment: Are you sure about that? If you manually encoded the query and passed like the answer below you're probably getting `/some_cool/view-mode=table`, i.e. not a query string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To build a query string from a Keyword List, you can use [`URI.encode_query/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/URI.html#encode_query/1):

```
iex(1)> URI.encode_query("view-mode": "table")
"view-mode=table"
```

---

But that doesn't seem to be the problem here. If your route has some required parameters, you need to specify all of them before passing the query Keyword List.

**For Example:**

- If your route is something like `/users`, your code above would work.
- But if it has a required parameter like `/users/:id`, you first need to pass the required argument(s) before specifying the Keyword List for the query string. So for this, you should call something like this:

  ```
  users_path(@conn, :show, @user.username, "view-mode": "table")
  ```

Comment: thanks. one more question: suppose I had an url with an "#" --> `example.com/something#as_table` or `example.com/something#as_chart`. How would I do pattern match on or deconstract it in a controller in an action? Meaning, it want to get the value after the `#`

Comment: It's called an Anchor or Fragment and it's not available on the serverside, only client-side. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687098/how-to-get-the-fragment-identifier-part-of-an-url).