# Handling pound sign (#) in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using requests to compile a custom URL and one parameter includes a pound sign. Can anyone explain how to pass the parameter without encoding the pound sign?

This returns the correct CSV file

```
results_url = 'https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/statcast_search/csv?all=true&hfPT=&hfAB=&hfBBT=&hfPR=&hfZ=&stadium=&hfBBL=&hfNewZones=&hfGT=R%7C&hfC=&hfSea=2019%7C&hfSit=&player_type=batter&hfOuts=&opponent=&pitcher_throws=&batter_stands=&hfSA=&game_date_gt=&game_date_lt=&hfInfield=&team=&position=&hfOutfield=&hfRO=&home_road=&hfFlag=&hfPull=&metric_1=&hfInn=&min_pitches=0&min_results=0&group_by=name&sort_col=pitches&player_event_sort=h_launch_speed&sort_order=desc&min_abs=0&type=#results'
results = requests.get(results_url, timeout=30).content
results_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(results.decode('utf-8')))
```

This DOES NOT

```
URL = 'https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/statcast_search/csv?'

def _get_statcast(params):

     _get = get(URL, params=params, timeout=30)
     _get.raise_for_status()
     return _get.content
```

The issue seems to be that when passing '#results' through requests anything after '#' gets ignored which causes the wrong CSV to be downloaded. If anyone has thoughts on other ways of going about this I would appreciate it.

EDIT2: Also asked this on the python forum https://python-forum.io/Thread-Handling-pound-sign-within-custom-URL?pid=75946#pid75946

Comment: Why do you _not_ want to encode the pound sign?

Comment: `www.example.com/type=%23results` sounds like the correct URL.

Comment: The `#` is a special character in uri **not** meant to be send to the server side. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side#answer-318581

Comment: @DYZ The url is a CSV download. '%23results' downloads a file I don't need and '#results' downloads the file I do need.

Comment: @Nick How do you know that `#` url works? Did you test it via browser? Browsers strip `#` sign before sending a request. Have you tried downloading **without** the pound suffix, i.e. the `www.example.com/type=#results` should be equivalent to `www.example.com/type=`. So basically just remove the pound suffix when you read the csv and you should be ok.

Comment: `#` is a reserved character as defined by RFC-3986. Whether or not you really need to *encode* it depends on what protocol you are using. However, whoever receives it should absolutely be *decoding* it.

Comment: @freakish Yes, I have tested it via browser. Simply removing # changes the CSV from the one I want to the one I don't want.

Comment: can you share the actual url?

Comment: You should provide a minimal working and verifiable example of what you are trying to do : what files do exist ? Where ? What are the transformations you perform between http request reception and the http request response ? As people said, # is special and you should work on encoding/decoding in order to return the correct data. %23 corresponds to #, and % is %25 (see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), so you can differentiate the two.

Answer (score 10):

Basically, anything after a literal pound-sign in the URL is *not* sent to the server. This applies to browsers and `requests`.

The format of your URL suggests that the `type=#results` part is actually a query parameter.

`requests` will automatically encode the query parameters, while the browser won't. Below are various queries and what the server receives in each case:

---

## URL parameter in the browser

When using the pound-sign in the browser, anything after the pond-sign is *not* sent to the server:

```
https://httpbin.org/anything/type=#results
```

Returns:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,de;q=0.7", 
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "*redacted*"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "method": "GET", 
  "origin": "*redacted*", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything/type="
}
```

- The URL received by the server is `https://httpbin.org/anything/type=`.
- The page being requested is called `type=` which does not seem to be correct.

---

## Query parameter in the browser

The `<key>=<value>` format suggest it might be a query parameter which you are passing. Still, anything after the pound-sign is *not* sent to the server:

```
https://httpbin.org/anything?type=#results
```

Returns:

```
{
  "args": {
    "type": ""
  }, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,de;q=0.7", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "*redacted*"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "method": "GET", 
  "origin": "*redacted*", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything?type="
}
```

- The URL received by the server is `https://httpbin.org/anything?type=`.
- The page being requested is called `anything`.
- An argument `type` without a value is received.

---

## Encoded query parameter in the browser

```
https://httpbin.org/anything?type=%23results
```

Returns:

```
{
  "args": {
    "type": "#results"
  }, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,de;q=0.7", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "*redacted*"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "method": "GET", 
  "origin": "*redacted*", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything?type=%23results"
}
```

- The URL received by the server is `https://httpbin.org/anything?type=%23results`.
- The page being requested is called `anything`.
- An argument `type` with a value of `#results` is received.

---

## Python requests with URL parameter

`requests` will also not send anything after the pound-sign to the server:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/anything/type=#results')
print(r.url)
print(r.json())
```

Returns:

```
https://httpbin.org/anything/type=#results
{
    "args": {},
    "data": "",
    "files": {},
    "form": {},
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Host": "httpbin.org",
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.21.0"
    },
    "json": null,
    "method": "GET",
    "origin": "*redacted*",
    "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything/type="
}
```

- The URL received by the server is `https://httpbin.org/anything?type=`.
- The page being requested is called `anything`.
- An argument `type` without a value is received.

---

## Python requests with query parameter

`requests` automatically encodes query parameters:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/anything', params={'type': '#results'})
print(r.url)
print(r.json())
```

Returns:

```
https://httpbin.org/anything?type=%23results
{
    "args": {
        "type": "#results"
    },
    "data": "",
    "files": {},
    "form": {},
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Host": "httpbin.org",
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.21.0"
    },
    "json": null,
    "method": "GET",
    "origin": "*redacted*",
    "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything?type=%23results"
}
```

- The URL received by the server is `https://httpbin.org/anything?type=%23results`.
- The page being requested is called `anything`.
- An argument `type` with a value of `#results` is received.

---

## Python requests with doubly-encoded query parameter

If you manually encode the query parameter and then pass it to `requests`, it will encode the already encoded query parameter again:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/anything', params={'type': '%23results'})
print(r.url)
print(r.json())
```

Returns:

```
https://httpbin.org/anything?type=%23results
{
    "args": {
        "type": "%23results"
    },
    "data": "",
    "files": {},
    "form": {},
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Host": "httpbin.org",
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.21.0"
    },
    "json": null,
    "method": "GET",
    "origin": "*redacted*",
    "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything?type=%2523results"
}
```

- The URL received by the server is `https://httpbin.org/anything?type=%2523results`.
- The page being requested is called `anything`.
- An argument `type` with a value of `%23results` is received.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I realize why the main CSV was getting returned regardless of any changes I made to the params.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Cloudomation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55482322/9075805) provides a lot of interesting information but I think it may not be what you are looking for. Assuming [this identical thread](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Handling-pound-sign-within-custom-URL) in the python forum is written by you as well, read on:

From the information you provided it seems that `type=#results` is being used **to filter the original csv** and return only parts of the data. 
 If this is the case, the `type=` part is not really necessary (try the URL without it and see that you get the same results).

**I'll explain:**

The `#` symbol in URLS is called a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and in different kinds of pages it serves different purposes. In `text/csv` pages, it serves **to filter** the csv table by column, row or some combination of the two. You can read more about it [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7111).

In your case, `results` could be a query parameter that is used to filter the csv table in a custom way.

Unfortunately, as illustrated in Cloudomation's answer, *the fragmented data is not available on the server side*, so you will not be able to access it via a python request parameter in the way you tried.

You could try to access it in Javascript [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687098/how-to-get-the-fragment-identifier-part-of-an-url) or simply download the entire (unfiltered) CSV table and filter it yourself.

There are many ways to do this easily and efficiently in python.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530301/how-to-filter-from-csv-file-using-python-script) for more information, or if you need more control you can import the CSV into a [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

**EDIT:**

I see you found a workaround by joining the strings and passing a second request. Since this works, you could probably get away with converting the params to string (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496750/how-to-prevent-python-requests-from-percent-encoding-my-urls)). If it does what you're after this would be a more efficient and perhaps *slightly* more elegant solution:

```
params = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'} // sample params dict

def _get_statcast_results(params):

    // convert params to string - alternatively you can  use %-formatting 
    params_str = "&".join(f"{k}={v}" for k,v in payload.items())

    s = session()

    data = s.get(statcast_url, params = params_str, timeout=30)

    return data.content
```

Comment: Lol, ya that was me on the python forum. I figured sooner or later I would get some sort of feedback between the two. Just to reiterate what I said at the top...I know requests in itself isn't the problem because I can pull the correct data without using params (I just need to use params in order to choose other specific situations, if that makes sense).

Comment: @Nick in the future when you cross-post on multiple sites, linking to them so that the question doesn't get answered twice is appreciated.

Comment: @micseydel I'll keep that in mind. Normally I just stick to asking here but wasn't getting much feedback and really need to get this solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've only gotten through one trial but hopefully have a solution. Instead of passing "#results' through params I started a session with the base url+all other params, joined that with "#results' and then ran it through a 2nd get.

```
statcast_url = 'https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/statcast_search/csv?'
results_url = '&type=#results&'

def _get_statcast_results(params):

    s = session()
    _get = s.get(statcast_url, params=params, timeout=30, allow_redirects=True)

    new_url = _get.url+results_url
    data = s.get(new_url, timeout=30)

    return data.content
```

Still need to run through some more trials but I think this should work. Thanks to everyone who chimed in. Even though I didn't get a direct answer the responses still helped a ton.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. My bet is it will work, and if so it will save you the second request.