# Use versions w/ github remote repositories (in this case w/ platformio)

Tags: github, version-control

This might be a basic github question, but I'm having trouble finding the right keywords to google because I don't know the terminology. Apologies and thanks in advance.

I've noticed with library dependencies in library.json, under "dependencies", there is often a github remote repo link with a version number after the #

For example
[https://github.com/codewitch-honey-crisis/htcw_ili9341.git#1.0.0"](https://github.com/codewitch-honey-crisis/htcw_ili9341.git#1.0.0%22)

What is that exactly after the #? A branch? A release?
More importantly, how do I make my github repo expose these. Like, I want to make a 1.0.0 one now for htcw_ili9341.git but later I may want to make 1.0.1

Using the github website, and/or the command line, how do I go about this?

It would be really helpful if you explained as you went as well.

So you know where I'm coming from with this, I've been using github for awhile but only for the most basic things, and driving it all through VS Code for the most part, sometimes resorting to the web interface and only occasionally dropping to the command line, which I've done a handful of times to resolve merge conflicts. I'm not an expert, but not completely new to it either.

Comment: Stuff after (and including) the `#` character is *not* sent to GitHub at all; see [this Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55435400/1256452) for instance. Other programs (browsers, yarn, whatever) can make any use they like of the `#` and suffix, but GitHub never even *see* it.

Comment: OMG, I feel so silly. I knew this. I know how HTTP works. I just completely spaced it off. For multiple hours apparently. *headdesk*. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Within the context of PlatformIO, and *only within that context*, the details after the # relate to the branch you want.

https://github.com/lvgl/lvgl.git#release/v7

Correlates to the "release/v7" branch on the lvgl repo.

Comment: thank you! I've since figured it out, but I still appreciate your response. sorry for the late reply. +1

Answer (score -1):

anything after # is never posted to the server. It's basically a comment in this specific instance.